# How to get test coverage for getters/setters

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to write a test class for a custom controller. The custom controller has the following variables which gets it's input from a VF page

```
public Ticket__c fromDateEvent{get;set;}
public Ticket__c toDateEvent{get;set;}
public Payment__c fromDateTransaction{get;set;}
public Payment__c toDateTransaction{get;set;}
```

How can I manually set these values in the test class.I tried  ticket.setfromDateEvent(..), but this is not working.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have not defined setter method as below

```
public Ticket__c fromDateEvent;

public void setfromDateEvent(Ticket__c ticket){
   this.fromDateEvent = ticket;
}
```

Your ticket.setfromDateEvent(..) wont work.

As you have defined it as a simple property you can directly assign value as below

```
Ticket_c t = new Ticket__c();
ticket.fromDateEvent = t;//directly assign the value
```

Comment: This is not working, my code coverage does not change..

Comment: Please share your entire test code and also the apex class code .Coverage not changing does not mean its not working .Is your getters and setters in blue ?

Comment: @gsanthan - You have to use these values somewhere for them to be covered. simply asserting the values in you test will cover them